# How to give a name to my forked Ethereum blockchain

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, blockchain-fork

I created my own private blockchain with Go Ethereum, now I want to put my own name for the symbol and network name. To do this, I checked the BSC code, it is a fork of Ethereum, and the BNB name in code is not specified anywhere. The guess I made myself is that the name is a contractual thing and it does not need to be defined somewhere, unlike the name of the token where we specify the symbol and the name, in fact we do not specify a place in naming the coin. And we just call our blockchain by this name and others know it by this name, is my guess right or am I wrong? , please help me.

Comment: A chain is typically identified by a chain/network id and not a name. So you'd want to configure a chainId for your network and metadata such as the name is managed/announced externally. See https://chainlist.org/

Answer (score 1):

Heyy Mehran Ra,

So If You Forked/Clone the Repo of geth and runned the Private Node

You must have made the Genesis.json there

Give them a Unique Chain Id there.

In Config File aka genesis.json you cant name the Chain because the Identity of the chain is Chain Id not the Name

If You have any doubt you can ask. ✌️